# Regular expression for 6 digit numeric input. Every 6 digits input numbers must be separated by comma

Tags: javascript, java, angularjs, db2, db2-400

My UI asks for the inputs User_ID and Supplier_ID and I wanted a string validation accept inputs for Supplier_ID like below:

```
1st scenario: 123456
2nd scenario: 123456,098765
3rd scenario: 123456,098765,345678
```

While it should not accept inputs like:

```
1st scenario: Any number less than 6 digits like 123
2nd scenario: Any number more than 6 digits 1234567
3rd scenario: Inputs with comma in the end or even at the beginning - 123456,098765,345678, or ,098765,345678
```

I will use the inputs for Supplier_ID on this query below:

```
UPDATE ABC.Items
SET Crit_Limit = 'Y' 
WHERE User_ID = 'userID'         
AND Supplier_ID in (suppID)
```

Variable suppID will carry the inputs from the UI Supplier_ID, so the query will look like this for example:

```
UPDATE ABC.Items
SET Crit_Limit = 'Y' 
WHERE User_ID = '007'         
AND Supplier_ID in (123456,098765,345678)
```

Anyway, the field Supplier_ID has a length 6 and must be numeric.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Java `!=` Javascript

Comment: What has been you tried?

Comment: I tried this one [0-9]{6} but it will only limit me to 6 digit, when I input for example 123456,098765 the program will give me an error as it will only satisfy 6 digit inputs. How can I use comma in the expression?

Comment: `([0-9]{6},)*[0-9]{6}`

Comment: Many thanks to Andy! This one works! :) ([0-9]{6},)*[0-9]{6} Thanks! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This pattern matches your test cases, and for any number of 6 digit groups separated by a comma.

```
^\d{6}(,\d{6})*$
```

Comment: Why do you have a `+` in there?

Comment: Thanks I'll give it a try

Comment: It didn't work even this one answered by Raising Spirit/^\d{6}(\,\d{6}){0,2}$/

Comment: Andy, it was a mistake!
ning-nung, from what I can see both this regex and the one provided by Raising Sprit are valid to check for the pattern.  Can you put up a pastebin link to show us how your using this?

Comment: I'm using it in hpoo system evaluator :) the one from Andy works fine.. Thanks to you all! :)

Answer (score 0):

this is the expresion you are looking for

```
^\d{6}(\,\d{6}){0,2}$
```

Comment: Thank you! Let me try all of those answers, and get back to you all.. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry but it Failed to satisfy the condition.. :(

Comment: where are you executing it? you may need to remove the / at he start and end if you are not in javascript

Answer (score 0):

Create your regex as searchgroups and check first for a newline followed by 6 digits, and then for `,` followed by 6 digits groups.

```js
['123456',
  '123456,098765',
  '123456,098765,345678',
  '123456,0987s65,345678',
  '12345,098765,345678',
  '123456/098765'
]
.forEach(function(line) {
  if (line.toString().replace(/(^\d{6}(,\d{6})*)/gm, '').length < 1) {
    console.log(line, "matches");
  } else {
    console.log(line, "does not match");
  }
});
```